# counter function returns wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have a data frame that looks like:

```python
p = {'parentId':['071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3', 'a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2', 'Highest Level', '071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3'],
     'id_x': ['a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2', 'd2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2', '071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3', 'a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = p)

df
|               parentId               |                 id_x                 |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 |
|             Highest Level            | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 |
```

Now I'm trying to create a new column that counts the number of `parentId` that match a specific `id_x`. The result should look like

```python
 df

|               parentId               |                 id_x                 | Amount |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | 1      |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 | 0      |
|              Highest Level           | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | 2      |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 | 0      |
```

Here is the function that I wrote to create this new column:

```python
def node_counter(id_x, parent_ID):
        for element in id_x:
            counter = 0
            for child in parent_ID:
                if child == element:
                        counter += 1
        return counter
```

I now apply it to the dataframe with apply/lambda and get the following result

```python
df['Amount'] = df.apply(lambda x: node_counter(x['id_x'], x['parentId']), axis=1)
df
|               parentId               |                 id_x                 | Amount |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------ |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | 4      |
| a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2 | d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2 | 6      |
|              Highest Level           | 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | 2      |
| 071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3 | a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184 | 2      |
```

What is wrong with my code and why do I not get the result that I intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong sets. Use all `parentId`s of the whole Dataframe for each comparison. And in the current `node_counter` step you don't need to loop over `id_x` since it's not a series.

```
def node_counter(id_x, parent_ID):
    counter = 0
    for child in parent_ID:
        if child == id_x:
            counter += 1
    return counter 
df['Amount'] = df.apply(lambda x: node_counter(x['id_x'], df['parentId']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                               parentId                                  id_x  Amount
0  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2       1
1  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2  d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2       0
2                         Highest Level  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3       2
3  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without the custom function and looping by instead using [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) together with [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) as follows.  This should give you more performance efficient and idiomatic coding:

```
df['Amount'] = df['id_x'].map(df['parentId'].value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)


print(df)

                               parentId                                  id_x  Amount
0  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2       1
1  a061e7d7-95d2-4812-87c1-24ec24fc2dd2  d2b62e36-b243-43ac-8e45-ed3f269d50b2       0
2                         Highest Level  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3       2
3  071cb2c2-d1be-4154-b6c7-a29728357ef3  a0e97b37-b9a1-4304-9769-b8c48cd9f184       0
```